# Certain files opened in Microsoft Word are looking for a flash drive to be plugged in

Tags: microsoft-word, usb-flash-drive

On two of my computers, numerous files are showing the following error when being opened:

If you click ok about 6 times, it'll eventually let you open up the file. Curiously, one of the computers that is having the issue never actually had the flash drive in question plugged into it.

I can't seem to find a similar issue online. I've tried disabling all of the COM addins, etc, just in case they were causing issues to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Are macros enabled? If yes, could you check with ALT+F11 if those Word files have VBA code somewhere?